# Swift to PHP; Sending Post requests from iOS to PHP server

Tags: php, swift, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am a web developer, and recently have started to learn Swift. I have been successful in communicating with PHP server, while using GET requests. However, I have yet to manage sending POST requests to the server. For example, traditionally when I submit the following HTML form to the server, I can easily get me variables as part of $_POST array on the server:

```
<form method="POST" action="www.something.com/submit_form.php">
 <input type="text" name="varName" value="someValue">
 <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am wondering if you can help me to find a way for sending a similar POST Request from Swift to "www.something.com/submit_form.php"

Your help is very much appriciated.

Comment: it is I asked the question in different form.

Comment: Please edit the previous question, rather than duplicating - this risks just creating more work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a POST request using [`NSMutableURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/HTTPMethod). You can set the HTTP Method to POST and build out the parameters you would like to send.

See ["Making a POST Request in Swift"](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/)

Comment: thx for your reply. I have already checked this webpage u suggested and it did not work for me.